# Python sqlite3 and string formatting - Error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, string-formatting

This is my code:

```
title = "Importunate Widow"
conn = sqlite3.connect('parable.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)

c.executescript("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _index(
                title text NOT NULL,
                context text NOT NULL
                );

            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(
                value int NOT NULL,
                number int NOT NULL,
                question text NOT NULL,
                choice1 text,
                choice2 text,
                choice3 text,
                choice4 text,
                answer text NOT NULL,
                explanation text,
                see text
                )""".format(title))

    c.executemany('INSERT INTO _index(title,context) VALUES(?,?)', index)

    c.executemany('INSERT INTO {}(value,number,question,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,answer,explanation,see) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'.format(title), quiz)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This gives me:

```
 OperationalError    Traceback (most recent call last)
 /home/user/Hobby/Quiz/quiz_sqlite.py in <module>()
sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
     87 
---> 88         c.executescript("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _index(title text NOT NULL,context text NOT NULL);CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(value int NOT NULL,number int NOT NULL,question text NOT NULL,choice1 text,choice2 text,choice3 text,choice4 text,answer text NOT NULL,explanation text,check text )""".format(title))
     89 
     90         c.executemany('INSERT INTO _index(title,context) VALUES(?,?)', index)

OperationalError: near "Widow": syntax error
```

I am basically iterating over multiple files and inserting data into tables named after the files. I have searched the internet and have turned up with nothing.

What I tried:

1. Tried adding `;` after the `)` before `"""`
2. Tried adding `,` after `see text`
3. Tried changing the name of the column `see` to `refer`

None of this helped!

What is the syntax error in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `Importunate Widow` as a table name. You're not allowed to use spaces in a table or field name.